# JavaScript & HTML changes not appearing through Django server

Tags: javascript, html, django, macos, server

I recently began a new job working on a Django server, and for some reason, the server stubbornly keeps refusing to propagate my updates.  This seems to be getting worse; sometimes I can make a change.  I've done a bunch of research and can't seem to get any closer to the problem.

- It is **NOT** due to my cache.  I've been consistently clearing my cache, closing my browser, and even occasionally restarting the computer.
- It's **NOT** due to server cache, either.  I've been stopping and starting the service with each test.
- It's not due to static files being updated.  I've even gone and changed all the static files manually, and I've repeatedly run manage.py collectstatic both with and without the -c flag.
- I tried appending a number to the JS url (adding "?rand=23423423" to the end of the script src links), as that was recommended to fix the JS problem, and that's when I found that the HTML wasn't updating either.

Changes made to .py files and CSVs always consistently work the first try.  Only JS and HTML files have not been propagating.

I'm working with Python 3.7, Django 2.1.5, Google Chrome 77.0.3865.90 and macOS (which I'd never worked with professionally before), if that makes any difference.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you give a specific example of a change that was not propagated? (Was it a change to template HTML, etc) The question right now is too broad, it could be a ton of different things.

Comment: An easy example is I added a call to console.log() before an error was being encountered in the .js in a script block (originally in a template HTML file which is interpreted into several static HTML files).  I used a project-wide find-and-replace to add the line to all instances across both the template and the existing static files, and verified that process was successful.